# How to upload JSON string to GCP bucket using Python without having to write it to a file?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have been uploading JSON file to GCP bucket like this

data_array is an array containing JSONs for each row. It looks like this "[{key1: value1, key2: value2},{key1: value1, key2: value2},{key1: value1, key2: value2}...]"

```
path_to_file = # i dump array to file   
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
#blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_file)


I want to skip this "dump to file" step and upload my array to GCP bucket directly.
blob.upload_from_string(path_to_file)
```

This throws an error , all red, I don't even understand why.

Is there any way to push array directly to bucket without having to write to file

Comment: Buckets store objects (files), not sure how you think the bucket stores something that is not a file. Maybe something it's not clear in the question. Can you explain better what are you trying to do?

Comment: upload_from_string write a string in an object in Cloud Storage. It works well when you provide a string. Here your provide an array. It's not a string and it fails. No surprise. Transform your array in a string (with a compose or whatever, but get a string, event in memory, no file to write here). Then provide that string to the function. It will work like a charm, I promise!

Comment: I want to upload an array, but not save it on my localhost, just upload that array to GCP and it should show up there as a file magically. is this doable

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i tried with ''.join() function to convert array to str, but still no result

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: Try this `data = str([{key1: value1, key2: value2},{key1: value1, key2: value2}])` and then `blob.upload_from_string(data)`

Comment: Your post does not have details on the values being stored. Are they strings or bytes, etc? Your problem is the conversion of Python data types to strings and is not related to Google Cloud Platform. If my previous comment does not work, edit your post with actual data examples.